# How to visualize the upstart scripts?

Tags: linux, boot, upstart, linaro

I am investigating the Linux (linaro based on Ubuntu14.04) boot issue, it is that the init scripts might be halt on some step.

So, is there a way to visualize that the service boot sequence based on the upstart ?

Any hints will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I hear that newer Ubuntu versions use systemd for booting which is configured via xml files. I heard that one of systemd's design goals was to increase concurrency during boot which will make the boot essentially non-deterministic, which in turn will not help debugging efforts. Perhaps there is a boot flag to start services and daemons sequentially for debug purposes?

Comment: [Bootchart](http://www.bootchart.org/) should be available on Ubuntu. It seems with systemd you can just use `systemd-analyze`, [see here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/710127/how-can-i-set-up-bootchart-in-ubuntu-15-10).

Comment: You may be interested in the kernel  command line arguments `systemd.crash_shell` (which opens a shell when it fails so that you can examine the system -- probably only possible or useful after some essential parts of the boot sequence have succeeded)  and `systemd.show_status` which just logs a note about what's going on to the console while it happens.